# Is it possible to ignore specific errors in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

During development, I use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE);
```

Sometimes, though rarely, there are specific `E_STRICT` errors I'd like to ignore.  But I don't want to turn off `E_STRICT` entirely.

Is there a way to ignore specific errors, whether via error code, or even, as hacky as it is, via string-comparing the error message itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: before problematic code again add error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE); -- or use @ before function

Comment: Hm, how would I do this if the error is being raised by a class definition?  For example, the specific error I want to ignore is: ``Strict Standards: Declaration of foo::test() should be compatible with that of bar::test()``.  (I am extending a class but purposefully wish for a derived method to take more parameters than the overridden method.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: That would indicate to me that you have some issues in your application architecture. PHP is trying to warn you of this, you shouldn't ignore those warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofcourse you can, look at [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), you pass name of your function, which will be called, when some error happen. There you can ignore errors, do what you want, or just send them to normal PHP error output.

Answer (score -1):

When you like to ignore specific error types then use the following format

error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE )

More information you'll find under http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: as everybody knows there are more then the given options. therefor my advice wasn't that bad. follow the link!